# Can I run a CLI command inside a flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, command-line-interface, desktop-application

[image: Sample Image]

When I click the `Boilerplate button` I want to run the CLI command `"flutter create projectName"` (inside a flutter `project/dar`t file)

I have already heard about

### process.run

```
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  // List all files in the current directory in UNIX-like systems.
  var result = await Process.run('ls', ['-l']);
  print(result.stdout);
}
```

&

### shell

```
var shell = Shell();

await shell.run('''

echo "hello world"

''');
```

But I don't know how to use in this situation

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process-class.html has a sample code on how to use `start` method

Comment: I have already visited this page and read all the content also tried to implement but it didn't get me any were, can you show me how the code will work in my situation

Comment: did you run the sample with `Process.start(...`? It shows how to read the output and how to write to input streams

Comment: import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  await Process.start('flutter create new',[]);
}